# How to create multiple members in a single array

Tags: c, structure

i will ask user for number of matrixes then randomize a 5x5 matrix for each one. Can i do this in a single struct. If so then how should i allocate memory for it, i try to do it this way but it didn't work.

```
struct Temp
{
    int *mat[5][5];

}test;

int main(void)
{
    

    int x;

    printf("Enter the number of matrixes : ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    test.mat= malloc( x* sizeof *test.mat);
    if (test.mat== NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *mat[5][5];
```

is a 5x5 array of `int*`.

To create a pointer to 5x5 array of `int`, it should be

```
int (*mat)[5][5];
```

Comment: I think the pointers aren't required, the OP just wants a 2D array of ints but doesn't quite get the whole pointer thing. Also, the malloc line probably doesn't want the deference in the sizeof.

Comment: @Skizz this answer is correct. The OP wants `x` count 5x5 `int` matrices (*"ask user for number of matrixes"*), and this is the way to get them. Also, the dereference isn't wrong, because it isn't an actual dereference, it's a type-of fed to a compile-time operator (`sizeof`), assuming the change Mike suggests is adopted.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, but I was wondering if the OP really wanted a structure containing a matrix of pointers to int. Wouldn't it be more sensible to create a structure containing a martrix of int, thus reducing the allocations required and reducing the possibility of getting memory leaks?